# Redirect old site to new address, but one page to new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, vhosts

I want to redirect all of my old domain request to my new domain, but except one subpage. One subpage from old site, must be redirect to URL on new site. For example:

siteA.com/* -> siteB.com/#/home/
siteA.com/documents -> siteB.com/#/home/addDocuments

Below is what I am using but it does not work, because old page with documents no redirect to new site with addDocuments, but only to home new page.

```
Redirect 301 /documents https://siteB.com/#/home/addDocuments 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dokumenty [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://siteB.com/ [L,R=301]
```

I must do it in vhost configuration file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

(on server siteA)
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /documents https://siteB.com/#/home/addDocuments
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ https://siteB.com